# How to use SyncAdapter for multiple request?

Tags: android, authentication, android-contentprovider, provider, android-syncadapter

I have more than one request to get data from server.
Is it posibble if I use one syncAdapter to handle it ? or need one syncAdapter for each request ?

if possible use one syncAdapter, please give some code snippet.

Comment: Yes, one SyncAdapter should be sufficient to sync multiple data.

Comment: hi @KNeerajLal, can you give some snippet code ? thanks

Comment: I can give a working example of a single request, not a multiple request. Is that sufficient?

Comment: hi @KNeerajLal, I already write my code for single request